# EventRelations removed from event after extra event update after an event insert

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, event

We have a situation where I have an apex class that first assembles an event given user input, inserts the event, then takes specified users that were invited via our UI, and creates EventRelations, and then inserts them.

We have found that a user using this has a process that kicks off if a certain field is filled out, and updates the event after it is inserted, which wipes out any EventRelations and reverts the event to its inserted state (with no event relations) with the update that the process is performing.

So problem: An update is performed on an event right after an insert, which prevents any changes to that events EventRelations from sticking, even though debug logs say the insert of that event relation performed successfully.

Has anyone encountered this and knows a way to circumvent it? Obviously Salesforce has some way of overcoming this issue, but in Apex, I have to insert the event, THEN insert the event relations, which allows triggers/processes to intervene in between and mess things up with extra event updates.

Comment: Seeing something similar in a unit test.  Tried changing the update to just include Event ids (only need to fire trigger, not change any data), but it's still dropping the EventRelations.  Wondering if it has something to do with EventWhoIds.  From the object ref:  "If you set the EventWhoIds field to null, all entries in the list are deleted...."  Shouldn't matter if I didn't query EventWhoIds to begin with, but still having the issue.